# Java is unable to execute _any_ file

Tags: java, freebsd

We have a few FreeBSD 10 servers and we are trying to get this tiny piece of code work right.

```
class H {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    (new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("/bin/echo")).start();
  }
}
```

With OpenJDK 1.7.0_55, it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/echo": error=2, No such file or directory
```

With OpenJDK 1.7.0_51, it is working.

Here is the output of `ls -l /bin/echo`

```
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6096 Mar 27 09:48 /bin/echo
```

Java is unable to find *any* file (and not just `/bin/echo`).

Comment: How are you running the code? From a command line, or from a (possibly jailed) web server?

Comment: `javac H.java; java H`

Comment: Can you try with Runtime.exec ?

Comment: @Toilal, same result.

Comment: Maybe you could open a bug issue on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues ... If you are running same user and context as u51, it's could be a bug in u55.

Comment: You could try with Oracle JVM too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7.55.13_3,1 to 7.55.13_4,1 upgrade appears to fix this problem for me. It was a problem for me too on the previous release only. More details of the patch can be seen here: http://www.freshports.org/java/openjdk7/ even though it doesn't immediately look like it would fix this issue.